# Rails: How to apply background-color to body

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Although I'd like to apply background color to body in my rails app, it doesn't work.

application.css

```
body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  ...
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion though this is an obvious question.

**SOLVED**

I changed the order of `require` in application.css.

before

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
...
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
```

after

```
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
...
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

Comment: Please try only "background:red"

Comment: Is the CSS even being loaded?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @anujsof. It doesn't work although I tried `background: red;`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Ronak Jain. Yes, CSS is loaded. When I try to add such as `.title { font-size: 10px;}`, it works.

Comment: Just add body {background: red;} in application.css it should work, otherwise some issue with your assets

Comment: Are you using bootstrap or a similar CSS framework which includes a 'reset.css' with well-defined values for certain CSS properties? Your browser's CSS inspector should reveal the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Thorin. It doesn't work when I try to add `body {background: red;}` in application.css. It would be appreciated if you could give me where I should check my asset.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Raffael. Although I use bootstrap3, it doesn't include a 'reset.css'. It would be appreciated if you could give me how to use `CSS inspector`. I use chrome. Of cause I will search how to use it by myself, but could you give me any advise?

Comment: In Chrome, right-click anywhere on the page and choose 'inspect'. Please find further instructions online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that CSS is loaded incorrectly. Make sure your CSS is loading. Right click on your page in chrome and go to 'element inspect'. Then in the right menu you can check if your CSS is loaded, which it will probably not. For more info on the inspector, check here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/?hl=en

Next, in your application.css you should be able to find the structure and sequence via which rails loads your css files. Look for something like this and make sure the "reset" is mentioned as first and your custom somewhere at the bottom.

```
    *= require reset
    *= require flexboxgrid
    ...
    *= require custom
```

Once the custom css file is loaded last (at the bottom in the application.css file), you can add in the custom.css file:

```
   body {
      background: red;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Thomas C.
I found that bootstrap was overwrited application.css when I checked `element inspect`.

So I rearranged the order of `require` in application.css, then it works.

I added the current settings at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
body {
  background: red;
}
```

This is work for you.

use background instead of background-color.
Also for best practices try to write down style in scss format instead of css

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Dheer. Although I tried same code in `custom.css.scss`, the result is the same.

Comment: Are you checked that there are no other override css ?
if yes then try body {
  background: red !important;
}

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Dheer. It works when I try `{ background: red !important; }`. But it works also when I try to change the sequence of `require` in application.css.

Comment: Cool @SamuraiBlue , it means style override due to wrong sequence.